# Inequality involving $f,f',f''$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to [0,+\infty)$ is strictly convex ($f''(x)\geq 0$) and is $\mathrm{C}^2$ with $\min f(x) = f(0) = 0$. If $f''(0) > 0$ then by Taylor's expansion around $0$, obviously 
$$ \limsup_{x\to 0} \left|\frac{f(x)}{\left[f'(x)\right]^2} \right|<+\infty.$$

My questions are,

> 1. If $f''(0) = 0$, what assumptions on $f$ do we need to ensure that $$
>    \limsup_{x\to 0}
>    \left|\frac{f''(x)f(x)}{\left[f'(x)\right]^2} \right|<+\infty? \qquad(*)$$
> 2. Can we prove $(*)$ if $f\in \mathrm{C}^3$? 
>      In other words, is it true that if $f\in C^3$ is strictly convex with $\min f = f(0) = 0$ then
>      $$ \limsup_{x\to 0} \frac{f''(x)f(x)}{f'(x)^2} < \infty?$$

Comment: strictly convex is is  $f''>0$

Comment: @zhw. Not if $f'' = 0$ holds only at a single point.

Comment: No, it only requires $f''\geq 0$. For example $x^4$ is strictly convex but $f''(0) = 0$.

Comment: You are right, both of you. Thanks. The way it was written, I thought it was being asserted that strictly convex was the same as $f''\ge 0.$

Comment: It's not clear to me what the hypotheses are. In 1, you seem to be saying all hypotheses above hold, except $f''(0)>0$ has been changed to $f''(0)=0.$ correct? In 2, what are we assuming?

Comment: I want to show that if $f\in C^3$ is strictly convex with $\min f = f(0) = 0$ then
$$ \limsup_{x\to 0} \frac{f''(x)f(x)}{f'(x)^2} < \infty.$$

Comment: It may be relevant to note that if $f(x)$ is a polynomial all of whose roots are real then for all $x$ one in fact has $f''(x)f(x) \leq f'(x)^2$.

Comment: @JoshuaZ: I thought if $f(x)$ is a polynomial then $(*)$ will be true no matter what roots it is.

Comment: @Sean , Yes. Note that the condition for real roots gives that there's no implied constant or limit. The inequality I mentioned is stronger than *.

Comment: @JoshuaZ: Thanks, can you give me the source for that inequality?

Comment: @Sean . First place  I saw it mentioned is in "Proofs From the Book" (which I don't have onhand and I don't remember why it was needed. It was a lemma there.) Proof sketch: Assume $f(x)$ has only real roots, $r_1, r_2 \cdots r_n$. So $$f(x) = k(x-r_1)(x-r_2 \cdots (x-r_n).$$ So $$\ln f(x) = \ln k +  \sum \ln (x-r_i).$$ Take the derivative of both sides: $$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \sum  (x-r_i)^{-1}.$$ Take the derivative  both sides again. $$\frac{f(x)f''(x)- f'(x)^2}{f(x)^2} = - \sum (x-r_i)^{-2}.$$ So $f(x)f''(x) - f''(x)^2$ is negative.

Comment: That last line should read "$f(x)f''(x)-f'(x)^2$ is negative."

Answer (score 2):

A partial answer. Note that $$\frac{f(x) f''(x)}{f'(x)^2} = 1 - \frac{d}{dx} \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}.$$ For analytic functions whose lowest-order Taylor series term is $c x^n$ with $n \geq 1$, we have $\dfrac{f(x)}{f'(x)} \sim \dfrac{cx^n}{ncx^{n-1}} = \dfrac{x}{n}$ for $x \approx 0$ and thus $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{d}{dx} \dfrac{f(x)}{f'(x)} = \dfrac{1}{n}$, and therefore $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) f''(x)}{f'(x)^2} = 1 - \frac{1}{n}.$$
Note that we made no assumption about the value of $f''(x)$; in fact, the limit is $1/2$ for any function with $f''(0) \neq 0$ (as you can verify algebraically for simple cases, e.g. $f(x) = x^2$).

Possibly this argument could be extended to non-analytic functions.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to get something more concrete. For example, using convexity one can get $f(x) \leq x f'(x)$, thus one can aim to show that
$$ \limsup_{x\to 0} \left|\frac{f''(x)x}{f'(x)} \right|< \infty$$
Or, one can prove that for $\mathrm{C^3}$ function with the above assumptions then $\limsup_{x\to 0} \frac{f''(x)}{\sqrt{f'(x)}} < \infty$, thus one can aim to show
$$ \limsup_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{|f'(x)|^{3/2}} < \infty$$